# cmp and je not working when comparing equal values

Tags: x86, cmp

[Homework disclaimer]

I'm working on the [binary bomb lab](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/README-bomblab). Basically, I have to use the objdump of a "bomb" executable to find the right input strings to disarm the "bomb." Currently I've solved 5/7 phases and am working on the 6th phase which contains this assembly:

```
 8048eb0:   39 18                   cmp    %ebx,(%eax)
 8048eb2:   74 05                   je     8048eb9 <phase_6+0x49>
 8048eb4:   e8 d0 0a 00 00          call   8049989 <explode_bomb>
```

To not explode the bomb, I need to set ebx and eax to same value so that `je` is called instead of the `explode_bomb` function. So, I found an input string that gives the same value of ebx and eax. However, when I reach this point in the program's execution, the `je` isn't called even though ebx and eax are the same value. In GDB:

```
Good work!  On to the next...
134530284

Breakpoint 2, 0x08048e74 in phase_6 ()
Current language:  auto; currently asm
(gdb) break *0x8048eb0
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8048eb0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, 0x08048eb0 in phase_6 ()
(gdb) print $ebx
$1 = 134530284
(gdb) print $eax
$2 = 134530284
(gdb) si
0x08048eb2 in phase_6 ()
(gdb) si
0x08048eb4 in phase_6 ()
(gdb) si
0x08049989 in explode_bomb ()
(gdb)
```

Why is this not working? This is the first time this assignment where this issue has come up.

Comment: Last time I checked `(%eax)` means load the value pointed to by `eax`, not `eax` itself. Though I'm not too familiar with this exact assembly syntax.

Comment: Yep, I was just being boneheaded. Whoops. Thank you, I found the right answer now. :)

Comment: Feel free to submit that as the solution so I can mark that as the best answer.

Comment: Made my answer. I had nearly the exact same project in one of my classes a few years back! Oh the nostalgia... :)

Comment: AT&T syntax makes me cranky.  No wonder you're having trouble.  It's much harder to manually parse than Intel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(%eax)` is not the same as `%eax`.

(%eax) means load the value pointed to by `eax`, not `eax` itself.